# What alternatives to Selenium WebDriver can I use for automated UI testing of a web application?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, ui-automation, cicd

I'm working on a project that currently uses Selenium WebDriver to run automated UI tests for a web-based application. However, Selenium is no longer being approved for use on this project. My team is currently investigating alternative solutions. We need something that can be used with a  CI/CD pipeline and that supports testing for multiple browser types. It would also be great if it can be integrated with Cucumber, which we also use currently, but this is not strictly necessary. I would love to hear your suggestions for anything that we can use. Thank you in advance!

Comment: requests for external resources/software/tools/libraries are off-topic here.

Comment: Why was Selenium refused?

Comment: It was a decision by the higher-ups that had nothing to do with Selenium's technical or functional capabilities

Comment: This happens when non-technical decides what technical should do, You can move to Katalon, it's getting popular nowadays, but it's limited to `Java` and `Groovy`

Comment: Katalon has Selenium under the hood. This is why I asked about what was the reason to refuse Selenium. We may advice something but without knowing the reason what would be wasteful.

Comment: A good point. Yeah, we unfortunately can't use Katalon if makes use of Selenium